# Вывести второе число среди самых больших (оно может совпадать с самым большим, если их два). Для последовательности: 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 0 ответ – 4

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

```
var
  a: integer;
  n, max, sum, kol, i, s: integer;

begin
  max := 1;
  a := 1;
  begin
    readln(n);
    for i:= 1 to n do 
    readln(a);
      begin
        if a > max then max := a; 
         if a < max then max := a; 
      end;
    end;


  writeln('Максимальное число  = ', max);

end.
```

Comment: Этот код и максимальное число не находит.

Comment: Слово "колличесво" пишется как-то по-другому.

Comment: Пардон, вставил не правильный код, теперь он находит максимум и слово количество изменено, это слово stackoverflow не понравилось

Comment: ввод - массив. Отсортировать элементы по убыванию => вывести второй элемент массива.

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Не надо сортировать.

Comment: Эх, Паскаль..  вот времена были)

Comment: Не находит. Это код находит последнее число, а не максимальное.

Comment: у вас такая интересная штука получается в коде....всю последовательность вы вводите с клавиатуры...так вот..вопрос нужен ли массив? может запукстить бесконечный цикл для ввода с клавиатуры, и при вводе просто высчитывать м аксмумы ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Начальная инициализация zmax1=max(a1,a2), zmax2:=min(a1,a2)
2. Поиск второго максимума

   ```
   begin

    readln(n);
    readln(zmax1);
    readln(a);

    if a>zmax1 then begin
                zmax2:=zmax1;
                zmax1:=a;
               end
          else zmax2:=a;

   for i:=3 to n do begin
    readln(a);
    if a> zmax1 then begin
      zmax2:=zmax1;
      zmax1:=a;
           end
    else
      if a>zmax2 then zmax2:=a;
    end;

   writeln(zmax2);

   end.
   ```

Comment: ой, ребят спасибо большое)

Comment: люблю не могу ❤❤❤

Comment: если вас устраивает решение, то можно отметить его как принятое (галочка)